# Is it a well-known inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality, reference-request, integral-inequality

> Let $f\in \mathcal{C}^2(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ and suppose that
>   $\int_\mathbb{R}f^2<+\infty$ and $\int_\mathbb{R}f''^2<+\infty$. Then
>   we can deduce that : $\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}f'^2\right)^2 \le (\int_\mathbb{R}f^2)(\int_\mathbb{R}f''^2)$.

In the standard proof, we use the famous inequality of Cauchy-Schwarz. However, I was wondering if there was a well-known mathematician who proved that statement and also for what kind of applications we can use it ? If someone has references it would be a nice idea to share.

*PS : there is a similar inequality called Landau-Kolmogorov.*

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I believe this is a special case of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gagliardo–Nirenberg_interpolation_inequality ?

Comment: @CalvinKhor I honestly do not know :'(

Comment: sorry, I phrased it with a ? but it wasn't a question, if you put $$ (j,m,n,p,q,r,\alpha) = (1,2,1,2,2,2,1/2)$$ then it recovers this result. I can't really name a direct use for it, but one easy consequence is the equivalence of the norm $\|f\|_{L^2} + \|f''\|_{L^2}$ and the usual sobolev norm $ \sqrt{\sum_{i=0}^2 \|f^{(i)}\|_{L^2}^2}$

Comment: @CalvinKhor I see ! There is just a constant $K$ which is missing with those data !

Comment: @Calvin Khor The link to wikipedia should be replaced by another link, for example https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01626613/document

Comment: @JeanMarie sorry, I would have searched for a better link but that's a comment that I can't edit now.Your link is great